# Bulk JSON data via POST to API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

This post is more about a coding approach to a problem rather than a problem itself (for a change!).

I have a number of projects that i'm working on the moment that require me to gather sales data from a number of disperate sources.

The data from each vendor is almost always accessed and structured in different ways; best case a nice valid JSON reponse, worst case I screen scrape the data.

As each vendor's source data is so different i've decided that a dedicated Rails-api App that feeds json data to a master sales-data App via it's API is the way forward.
I did look at using Sinatra for each vendor app but my knowledge is with Rails so I can get things done much quicker. I feel a dedicated app for each vendor app is the right approach as these can be maintained independently and should a vendor decide to start feeding their data themselves, I (or another developer) can easily swap things over without having to delve into one massive monothlic sales data gathering app, however, do say if you think dedicated apps doesn't make much sense.

So, as a simple stripped down example, each vendor app is structured around a class like this. Currently i'm just calling the methods via console, but will automate via rake tasks and background workers eventually.

```
class VendorA < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.get_report
    # Uses Mechanize Gem to fetch a report in CSV format
    # returns report
  end

  def self.save_report(report)
    # Takes the report from the get_report method and saves it, currently to the app root but eventually this will be S3
    # returns the local_report
  end

  def self.convert_report_to_json(local_report)        
    # Reads the local report, iterates through it grabbing the fields required for the master sales-data app and constructs a JSON repsonse
    # returns a valid JSON repsonse called json_data
  end

  def self.send_to_master_sales_api(json_data)
    # As you can see here I take the repsonse from convert_report_to_json and post it to my sales data App
    require 'rest-client'
    RestClient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sales/batch', json_data)
  end

end
```

This works fine with the send_to_master_sales_api method doing what is expected. I haven't yet tested this beyond approx 1000 data objects/lines though.

On the receiving end, at the master sales-data App, things look like this:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SalesController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :restrict_access
      skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
      respond_to :json

      def batch
        i = 0
        clientid = params[:clientid]
        objArray = JSON.parse(params[:sales])
        objArray.each do |sale|
          sale = Sale.new(sale)
          sale.clientid =  clientid   #Required / Not null
          sale.save
          i +=1
        end 
        render json: {message: "#{i} Sales lines recevied"}, status: 202
      end


      private
      def restrict_access
        api_key = ApiKey.find_by_api_key_and_api_secret(params[:api_key],params[:api_secret])
        render json: { message: 'Invalid Key - Access Restricted' }, status: :unauthorized unless api_key
      end

    end
  end
end
```

So, my main question is really about the volume of JSON data you think this approach can handle. As I mentioned above, i've tested with around 1000 lines/objects and it worked fine. But should I start having to process data with one of the vendor apps where i'm approaching say, 10,000, 100,000 or even 1,000,000 lines/objects per day from each source what should I be thinking about in terms of the above two apps being able to cope. Is there something like find_in_batches I could be using to ease the load of receiving the data? Currently I plan to write the master sales-data records to a Postgres DB. While i've limited experience of NoSQL, would writing to MongoDB or similar speed things up at the receiving end?

I realise this isn't a particularly direct question, but I would really appreicate input and thoughts from those with experience of this kind of thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't forget about [`each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) that makes the dance you're doing there with `i` a non-issue, as you either need that or `objArray.length`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip. Bit of a habit doing the i+=1 thing.

Comment: Are you pulling data or is it getting pushed to you? I think Postgres would be fine here. There's no reason to pull the pin on using MongoDB.

Comment: Pulling in nearly all cases, but we're trying to get some vendors to push to us as the data we're pulling in some cases is awful. Good to hear you think Postgres will be ok. What do you mean by 'There's no reason to pull the pin on using MongoDB'?

Comment: MongoDB is not a magic bullet, and in some cases it can be a lot harder to use effectively because it's not a regular relational database. Unless you're dealing with massive scale and are prepared to architect something specifically to how MongoDB works best, you'd be better served by using Postgres. Also, if this is primarily pull, you should consider creating some tasks you can kick off on a regular schedule to pull down new data and push it into the database directly through ActiveRecord. `rake` tasks can do this pretty effectively when coupled with `cron` to schedule.

Comment: Yeah I hear what you're saying. I use MongoDB a little, but it's just for ad-hoc map-reduce tasks. I'm yet to build in into an app. I'm definitely planning some rake tasks to handle pulling the data etc.